# How can I block incoming calls from a particular phone number on an Ubuntu phone?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, phone

I have a Meizu Ubuntu phone, and I am getting repeated incoming calls from the same number.

I may be being stupid, but I have been unable to find a way of blocking those calls.

Is this possible?

Comment: Just from a quick search, there doesn't seem to be anything ATM, but don't give up.

Answer (score 3):

[F-Call](https://f-call-dev.blogspot.com/) is available now that does call filtering but installation is through terminal.

Comment: Where can I find information on F-Call? I've tried searching, but can't find anything that matches.
Thanks

Comment: http://f-call-dev.blogspot.com  , welcome.

Comment: Got it installed, now in touch with the developers to try & get it working.